# Convert Binary Tree to Doubly Linked List - Python - Error Message

Tags: python, binary-tree, doubly-linked-list

Please help me with the LeetCode problem [Convert binary search tree to sorted doubly linked list](https://leetcode.com/problems/convert-binary-search-tree-to-sorted-doubly-linked-list/):

> Convert a Binary Search Tree to a sorted Circular Doubly-Linked List in place.
>
> You can think of the left and right pointers as synonymous to the predecessor and successor pointers in a doubly-linked list. For a circular doubly linked list, the predecessor of the first element is the last element, and the successor of the last element is the first element.

I am trying to solve it - I know not in the optimal way - but I would like to at least get a valid answer. Although it looks to me that the list is sorted and it is doubly linked and that the pointers point to the correct values, I cannot get the correct solution.

I am getting the error:

> The linked list [1,2,3,4,5] is not a valid circular doubly linked list.

Below is my code

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def inOrderTraversal(node, array):
    if node == None:
        return

    inOrderTraversal(node.left, array)
    array.append(node.val)
    inOrderTraversal(node.right, array)
    return array


class Solution:
    def treeToDoublyList(self, root: 'Optional[Node]') -> 'Optional[Node]':
        if root is None:
            return None
        array = []
        inOrderTraversal(root, array)

        head = Node(array[0])
        head.left = Node(array[-1])
        prev_node = head

        for i in range(1, len(array)):
            num = array[i]
            node = Node(num)


            prev_node.right = node     
            node.left = prev_node
            prev_node = node

            if i == len(array) - 1:
                node.right = head


        count = 0
        node = head
        while count < 5:
            print("new Test")
            print(node)
            print(node.left.val)
            print(node.right.val)
            node = node.right
            count += 1

       # print(head.right.val)

        return head
```

Printed output is:

```
new Test
<__main__.Node object at 0x7f0318a062c0>
5
2
new Test
<__main__.Node object at 0x7f0318a06a40>
1
3
new Test
<__main__.Node object at 0x7f0318a06c20>
2
4
new Test
<__main__.Node object at 0x7f0318a3e680>
3
5
new Test
<__main__.Node object at 0x7f0318a3e6e0>
4
1
```

I added this output so to make sure that the doubly linked list is fine, but the test framework says it is not.

Where is the generated doubly linked list wrong, when I give a BST as input that has 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 as values?

Comment: Please include a [mre] with emphasis placed on **minimal**. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `head.left` is assigned a `Node` instance that is not the node that will be created in the last iteration of the loop. So you have *two* tail nodes. Another way to see something is wrong, is to count the number of times you call `Node()`: it is one time too many.

When you then walk forward through the list, all will be OK, but when you walk backward from the `head` to the previous node, that node's `left` attribute will still be `None`.

The solution is to remove this line from your code:

```
    head.left = Node(array[-1])
```

And also these lines from the loop -- they are not wrong, but it is more natural to just do that action *after* the loop has finished:

```
      if i == len(array) - 1:
            node.right = head
```

And now *after* the loop, do this (when `node` is the *last* node in the list):

```
    node.right = head
    head.left = node
```

### Some ideas for improvement

- Turn `inOrderTraversal` into a generator.
- Make use of the `Node` constructor's capability to set a `left` attribute via its argument

```
def inOrderTraversal(node):
    if node == None:
        return
    yield from inOrderTraversal(node.left)
    yield node.val
    yield from inOrderTraversal(node.right)


class Solution:
    def treeToDoublyList(self, root: 'Optional[Node]') -> 'Optional[Node]':
        if root is None:
            return
        iterator = inOrderTraversal(root)
        head = Node(next(iterator))
        prev_node = head

        for val in iterator:
            node = Node(val, prev_node)
            prev_node.right = node     
            prev_node = node

        node.right = head
        head.left = node
        return head
```